# show some specific items from a list with map

Tags: reactjs

I want to understand how to display certain items of a list with the Map() function of react.
To illustrate my situation I have created a codesandbox with my problems:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-713xy

**In this example I want to display the number of "gun" that each character has.**
But without changing the code too much if possible because my real code is more complex than this example.

**I don't want show all objects they have, only the quantity of gun(s)**

thanks

Comment: There you go https://codesandbox.io/s/test-uz-forked-70btq?file=/src/test.js